# get multiple values form the database and show in combo box and different text boxes when the index change c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

```
   try
        {
           // var model =Execute.q"SELECT product.id, product.productName, product.unitId, product.productCode, units.name FROM product INNER JOIN units ON product.unitId = units.id";

            string query1 = "SELECT product.id, product.productName, product.unitId, product.productCode, units.name FROM product INNER JOIN units ON product.unitId = units.id";
            command = DBConnectivity.getCommandForQuery(query1, connection);
            dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            int reslut = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.cBproductName.DisplayMember = "productName";
            this.cBproductName.ValueMember = "id";
            datarow = dataset.Tables[0].NewRow();
            datarow["productName"] = "Select Product";
            dataset.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(datarow, 0);
            this.cBproductName.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
 private void cBproductName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cBproductName.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            txtProCode.Text = this.cBproductName.SelectedValue.ToString();

        }
    }
```

i want to show product code and the unit name in the text boxes against the id in the product table and on the change on selected index in the combo box cBproductName. my query give me all the values but unable to show in the form.

Comment: use datareaders to fill textboxes

Comment: `this.cBproductName` is a new object and has nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the SQL statement to include the informations you need.

Like:

```
SELECT product.productName + ' ' + product.productCode + ' ' + units.name  AS ShowText, product.id, product.productName, product.unitId, product.productCode, units.name FROM product INNER JOIN units ON product.unitId = units.id
```

Change cBproductName_SelectedIndexChanged method to:

```
DataRow row = this.cBproductName.SelectedItem as DataRow;
if (row != null)
{
  txtProCode.Text = row["ShowText"].ToString();
}
```

The ComboBox i bound to a DataSet that contains DataRow elements.

Comment: this shows all the values product name , product code and unit name in the combo box, but i want just product name in combo box and all the other values product code, id and unit id and unit name in different text areas. please help me

Comment: I have updated the answer. The CombBox is bound to a DataSet, and that DataSet contains DataRow elements. If you use ComboBox.SelectedItem that will be a DataRow